# Search filter using rxjava1 android(java)

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I have a list and i got search filter. I have done using EditText listeners and using for loop. But i want the filter should handle by rxjava

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Search text: " + charSequence);
    List<AllAttendance> list = new ArrayList<>();

    //filter from all List

    if (rbtnAll.isChecked())
        list = filter(mAttendanceList, charSequence);
    else if (rbtnPending.isChecked())
        list = filter(mPendingAttendanceList, charSequence);

    setAdapterData(list);
    rvAttendance.scrollToPosition(0);
}

private List<AllAttendance> filter(List<AllAttendance> mAttendanceList, CharSequence charSequence) {

    String text = String.valueOf(charSequence);
    text = text.toLowerCase();

    List<AllAttendance> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (AllAttendance attendance : mAttendanceList){

        if (attendance.getMandalName().toLowerCase().contains(text) || attendance.getSabhaName().toLowerCase().contains(text) || attendance.getSabhaDate().toLowerCase().contains(text))
            filteredList.add(attendance);
    }
    return filteredList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code i have used for searching with `AndroidRx`.

**NOTE** : In this example i am making a network call on every character change after waiting for 1000 ms.

```
 PublishSubject<String>  subject = PublishSubject.create();

    subject.debounce(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .filter(new Predicate<String>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(@NonNull String s) throws Exception {
                    return s.length() > 0;
                }
            })
            .switchMap(new Function<String, Observable<SearchViewResponseModel>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<SearchViewResponseModel> apply(@NonNull String o) throws Exception {
                    return api.getSearchResult(PrefsManager.getToken(SearchActivity.this), o, 0, 10);
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<SearchViewResponseModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(@NonNull SearchViewResponseModel s) {
                    adapter.clear();
                    for (SearchViewResponseModel.Data model : s.getData())
                        adapter.add(new SearchViewModel(model.get_id(), model.getThumbnail(), model.getTitle()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.i("Completed", "");
                }
            });

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String newText) {
            subject.onNext(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```